# Can Rascal return the operating system in method?

Tags: rascal

In java I would use: System.getProperty("os.name") to get Java to return the operating system.
Is something similar possible in Rascal?
My goal is to write a method to write text files to a folder that works OS-independent.
Something like;

```js
 public void writeTextFile(){
  if OS = "macOS" write text to "/Users/Shared/text.txt"
  if OS = "Windows" write text to "c:\text.txt"
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just use a home URL like `home:///path/to/file` the writeFile function will take care of the rest. There is also `cwd://` for the current working directory and `tmp:///` for the temp folder.

Answer (score 1):

A more direct answer, but it will not lead to better code. You can use the API from `util::SystemAPI`:

```
rascal>import util::SystemAPI;
ok    
rascal>getSystemProperty("os.name")
str: "Mac OS X"
```

But, the other answer is better, since Rascal's `loc` data-type is supposed to provide a file system abstraction that works the same on all operating systems.